$\infty$-category of spectra and cofibrancy
I have two options for the $\infty$-category of spectra. I would like to know they are equivalent as $\infty$-categories.
Premise: by work of Dwyer and Kan, if we have a simplicial model category, the subcategory on fibrant-cofibrant object is equivalent to its localization, i.e., it is a good model for the $\infty$-category presented by the simplicial model category.
Option $C_1$: this is the stabilization of the $\infty$-category of spaces. To be more concrete, the spectrum objects ("spectrum" means $\Omega$-spectrum here) on the the fibrant-cofibrant (pointed) Simplicial sets, i.e. Kan Complexes. This is close to how Lurie defines the category in higher algebra.
Option $C_2$: take the stable simplicial model category of spectra and consider its fibrant-cofibrant objects. For example, take the sequential prespectra (which have values in pointed simplicial sets) with the Bousfield-Friedlander model structure.
Here being fibrant-cofibrant means being an $\Omega$-spectrum with values Kan complexes (fibrant) and having cofibration structure maps (cofibrant).
So as we see the cofibrancy condition is not encoded in $C_1$. Why is this not important?
How can I show $C_1\cong C_2$ as $\infty$-categories?

The bifibrant replacement map induces a Dwyer–Kan equivalence $C_1→C_2$ of simplicial categories, which answers the question in the affirmative.

I'm new to this stuff. Could you expand a bit or give a reference? Thanks.

The reference is the work of Dwyer and Kan that you already mentioned in your question.  For instances, Propositions 4.8 and 5.2 in Function complexes in homotopical algebra.

I think you're saying that $C_2$ is equivalent to the localization at the fibrant prespectra by Dwyer and Kan, and then this localization in turn is equivalent to $C_1$. Is that correct? I don't quite see the second equivalence, though it sounds plausible.

I am not sure where fibrant prespectra came from, since they are not mentioned in my comments or your question.   The bifibrant replacement functor $F\colon C_1→C_2$ and the inclusion functor $G\colon C_2→C_1$ are relative functors between relative categories and admit natural weak equivalences connecting $FG$ and $GF$ to the corresponding identity functors.  This implies that the two relative categories are weakly equivalent.  Such data induces a weak equivalence of the corresponding simplicial categories, e.g., their hammock localizations or Dwyer–Kan simplicial localizations.
